# Get index of an element mongodb aggregation

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my collection

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c225f9a66d39d55c036fa66"),
        "name" : "Sherlock",
        "mobile" : "999999",
        "adress" : [
                {
                        "street" : "221b baker street",
                        "city" : "london"
                },
                {
                        "street" : "ben street",
                        "city" : "london"
                }
        ],
        "tags" : [
                "Detective",
                "Magician",
                "Avenger"
        ]
}
```

Now I want to get the first or second value inside address array.
for that I'm using this command.

```js
> db.agents.findOne({"name" : "Sherlock"},{"adress" : 1})
```

but instead of giving a single result it is giving the entire array like

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c225f9a66d39d55c036fa66"),
        "adress" : [
                {
                        "street" : "221b baker street",
                        "city" : "london"
                },
                {
                        "street" : "ben street",
                        "city" : "london"
                }
        ]
}
```

It can be done by comparing array value like

```js
 db.agents.find({"adress.street": "ben street"}, {_id: 0, 'adress.$': 1});
```

But I don't want to compare just to print the array indexes. How can I get the single result? 
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to get the specific element from the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$adress", 0] }}   //index
])
```

and if you want to get the sliced element then you can use [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection

```
db.collection.find({}, { adress: { $slice: [2, 1] }})  // 2 index and 1 number of element
```

Comment: I was able to get the the array elements by slice where 2 seems like offset and 1 is limit. But for the first one how do you create $addfields value. I read about it is used in aggregate but it is giving error. Not accepting '$' in $addfields and after removing it pipeline error.

Comment: what is your mongdb version?

Answer (score 2):

You can `$unwind` with `includeArrayIndex` to get the index of address array

```
db.t11.aggregate([
    {$match : {"adress.street" : "ben street"}},
    {$unwind : {path : "$adress", includeArrayIndex : "idx"}},
    {$match : {"adress.street" : "ben street"}}
]).pretty()
```

you can add `$project` to filter the fields not required

result

```
> db.t11.aggregate([{$match : {"adress.street" : "ben street"}},{$unwind : {path : "$adress", includeArrayIndex : "idx"}},{$match : {"adress.street" : "ben street"}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c225f9a66d39d55c036fa66"),
        "name" : "Sherlock",
        "mobile" : "999999",
        "adress" : {
                "street" : "ben street",
                "city" : "london"
        },
        "tags" : [
                "Detective",
                "Magician",
                "Avenger"
        ],
        "idx" : NumberLong(1)
}
>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I don't want to use name of the street or anything in query. I just want to load the address by array index. How can I do that.